# How To check if there is a new version of my app in the App Store on Swift5?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, app-store

I am currently checking my app version. My apps are notified if there is a new version and should the `App Store` screen, press the OK. I am checking the app version to do it, but it always shows an error.

```swift
    func isUpdateAvailable(completion: @escaping (Bool?, Error?) -> Void) throws -> URLSessionDataTask {
        guard let info = Bundle.main.infoDictionary,
            let currentVersion = info["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String,
            let identifier = info["CFBundleIdentifier"] as? String,
            let url = URL(string: "http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=\(identifier)") else {
                throw IXError.invalidBundleInfo
        }
        Log.Debug(currentVersion)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            do {
                if let error = error { throw error }
                guard let data = data else { throw IXError.invalidResponse }
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [.allowFragments]) as? [String: Any]
                guard let result = (json?["results"] as? [Any])?.first as? [String: Any], let version = result["version"] as? String else {
                    throw IXError.invalidResponse
                }
                completion(version != currentVersion, nil)
            } catch {
                completion(nil, error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
        return task
    }
```

**Usage**

```swift
        _ = try? isUpdateAvailable { (update, error) in
            if let error = error {
                Log.Error(error)
            } else if let update = update {
                Log.Info(update)
            }
        }
```

### Is this because my app doesn't have an app store?

1. **If I have an app store, What response can I get to know if I have a version to update?**
2. **How can I go to the App Store?**

Please help me a lot.

Comment: That endpoint seems to be returning empty for me when I provide my own bundle identifier so try check if the file has any results.

This solution doesn't seem very scalable or reliable anyway, I'd recommend hosting a file somewhere that contains the version number. It's a bit more overhead but is more reliable

Comment: @DavidLiaw Are you saying that the function I use is not good? Then would you please offer me a better solution??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the method you use must be an already published app.

If you use an unpublished app, you will get `results = []`

Go to the `App Store` like this

```
let appId = "1454358806" // Replace with your appId
let appURL = URL.init(string: "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/cn/app/id" + appId + "?mt=8") //Replace cn for your current country

UIApplication.shared.open(appURL!, options:[.universalLinksOnly : false]) { (success) in

}
```

#### Note:

This method will not be very timely, meaning that the application you just released, even if it can be searched in the `App store`, but `results` will not be updated immediately. Update information will be available after approximately 1 hour, or longer

Comment: Thank you for a good idea. However, the screen needs to be changed to asynchronous mode when moving the screen, so the black screen is displayed briefly and then moved to the screen. How should I do this?

Comment: What do you mean, I don't understand much.

Comment: When using the 'isUpdateAvailable' function, screen movement should be disabled. Otherwise, it will operate slowly. However, when using the asynchronous machine, the black screen is briefly displayed and then moved to the screen I specified.

Comment: And where can I get my app ID?

Comment: appId is available in the account center, provided you create a publishing app. https://developer.apple.com/account/.  Did you point out the black screen before entering the `app store`? I will check it carefully.

Comment: I'll pop up a notification window when there's an app in the app store to update, and I'll go to the app store when I press the OK button. But when I see the notice window, I can see the black screen for a while.

Comment: How pop up a notification window, it is best to look at the code

Comment: Using 'DispatchQueue.main.async' to move the screen, the black screen is displayed and then moved to the screen.

Comment: Sorry, I can't restart the black screen you said. I use the `UIAlertController` popup window without a black screen, you check if the code is correct, I am using `present` popup

Answer (score 3):

I have implemented this way to update my new version.

step 1: I have saved my current version which will going to be live.
exa:

```
struct appVersion {
static let version = "1.3.45"
```

}

Step 2: Check my app version which has already saved that is equal to live app or not.

exa:

```
if userDefaults.value(forKey: "liveAppVersion") != nil {
        if userDefaults.string(forKey: "liveAppVersion") != appVersion.version {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1){
                self.alertUpdate(msz: ConstantStr.updateStr.val, titleStr: "Alert!", btntext: "Update") { success in
                    if success == true {
                        if let url = URL(string: "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id1462877960") {
                            UIApplication.shared.open(url)
                        }
                    }}
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    else {
        UpdateVersion.share.appUpdateAvailable { success in
            if userDefaults.string(forKey: "liveAppVersion") != appVersion.version {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1){
                    self.alertUpdate(msz: ConstantStr.updateStr.val, titleStr: "Alert!", btntext: "Update") { success in
                        if success == true {
                            if let url = URL(string: "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id1462877960") {
                                UIApplication.shared.open(url)
                            }
                        }}
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

step3: This method will check the current version from app store.

exa:

```
     func appUpdateAvailable(handler:@escaping(Bool?) -> ())
{
    let storeInfoURL: String = "http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=com.test.app"
      let urlOnAppStore = NSURL(string: storeInfoURL)
        if let dataInJSON = NSData(contentsOf: urlOnAppStore! as URL) {
            // Try to deserialize the JSON that we got
            if let dict: NSDictionary = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dataInJSON as Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! [String: AnyObject] as NSDictionary {
                if let results:NSArray = dict["results"] as? NSArray {
                   if let version = (results[0] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "version") {
                       userDefaults.set(version, forKey: "liveAppVersion")
                        handler(true)
 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
   }
```

-> For alert method, when tapped the update button can jump to App Store for update current version:

```
func alertUpdate(msz: String, titleStr : String, btntext: String,handler:@escaping(Bool?) -> ()){
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: titleStr, message: msz, preferredStyle: .alert)
   
    let ok = UIAlertAction(title: btntext, style: .default) { alert in
       handler(true)
   }
   
    alert.addAction(ok)
    self.present(alert, animated: true)
}
```

Finally!
you can this popup for update
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have done this via a completion handler

```
func appStoreVersion(callback: @escaping (Bool,String)->Void) {
    let bundleId = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleIdentifier"] as! String
    Alamofire.request("https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=\(bundleId)").responseJSON { response in
      if let json = response.result.value as? NSDictionary, let results = json["results"] as? NSArray, let entry = results.firstObject as? NSDictionary, let appStoreVersion = entry["version"] as? String{
        callback(true,appStoreVersion)
      }else{
        callback(false, "-")
        }
    }
  }
```

appStoreVersion contains your app version on app store. Remember: When your app goes live on app store, it may take up to 24 hours until you see the latest version.
Here is how to use it:

```
appStoreVersion { (success,version) in
            appVersion = version
            self.VersionLabel.text = "App version \(appVersion)"

        }
```

You can use the success version to do a different things it version cannot be retrieved. i.e. you are not connected or.
You can check how it is used in this app(Settings Tab):
https://apps.apple.com/us/app/group-expenses-light/id1285557503

Comment: How do I use it when I try to use it?

Answer (score 0):

I have used the completion handler too.

```
private func getAppInfo(completion: @escaping (AppInfo?, Error?) -> Void) -> URLSessionDataTask? {
    guard let identifier = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleIdentifier"] as? String,
        let url = URL(string: "http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=\(identifier)") else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(nil, VersionError.invalidBundleInfo)
            }
            return nil
    }
```

```
private func getVersion() {
_ = getAppInfo { info, error in
                if let appStoreAppVersion = info?.version {
                    let new = appStoreAppVersion.components(separatedBy: ".")
                    if let error = error {
                        print("error getting app store version: \(error)")
                    } else {
                        print(new)
                    }
}
```